# Separate dataframe into multiple ones and add them as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

my dataset look similiar to this (but with a couple of more rows):

[image: Raw data]

The aim is to get this:

[image: Aim]

What I tried to do is:

```
# Identify names that are in the dataset
names = df['name'].unique().tolist()

# Define dataframe with first name
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = df[(df == names[0]).any(axis=1)]
df1 = df1.drop(['name'], axis=1)
df1 = df1.rename({'color':'color_'+str(names[0]), 'number':'number_'+str(names[0])}, axis=1)

# Make dataframes with other names and their corresponding color and number, add them to df1
df_merged = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1, len(names)):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2 = df[(df == names[i]).any(axis=1)]
    df2 = df2.drop(['name'], axis=1)
    df2 = df2.rename({'color':'color_'+str(names[i]), 'number':'number_'+str(names[i])}, axis=1)
    df_merged = df1.join(df2, lsuffix="_left", rsuffix="_right", how='left')
```

In the end I get this result for df_merged:

[image: Result]

As you can see the columns color_Donald and number_Donald are missing. Does anyone know why and how to improve the code? It seems as if the loop somehow skips or overwrites Donald.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of posting images please post a dictionary so we can reproduce the data set easily. Example: print(df.to_dict())

Comment: Raw data: {'name': {Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'): 'Justin', Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'): 'Justin', Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'): 'Donald'}, 'color': {Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'): 'blue', Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'): 'red', Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'): 'green'}, 'number': {Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'): 1, Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'): 2, Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'): 9}}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line:

```
df_merged = df1.join(df2, lsuffix="_left", rsuffix="_right", how='left')
```

where `df_merged` will be set in the loop always to the join of `df1` with current `df2`.

The result after the loop is therefore a join of `df1` with the last `df2` and the `Donald` gets lost in this process.

To fix this problem first join empty `df_merged` with `df1` and then in the loop join `df_merged` with `df2`.

Here the full code with the changes (not tested):

```
# Identify names that are in the dataset
names = df['name'].unique().tolist()

# Define dataframe with first name
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = df[(df == names[0]).any(axis=1)]
df1 = df1.drop(['name'], axis=1)
df1 = df1.rename({'color':'color_'+str(names[0]), 'number':'number_'+str(names[0])}, axis=1)

# Make dataframes with other names and their corresponding color and number, add them to df1
df_merged = pd.DataFrame()
df_merged = df_merged.join(df1) # <- add options if necessary
for i in range(1, len(names)):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2 = df[(df == names[i]).any(axis=1)]
    df2 = df2.drop(['name'], axis=1)
    df2 = df2.rename({'color':'color_'+str(names[i]), 'number':'number_'+str(names[i])}, axis=1)
    # join the current df2 to df_merged: 
    df_merged = df_merged.join(df2, lsuffix="_left", rsuffix="_right", how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

sample df

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'name': {'2020-01-01 00:00:00': 'Justin', '2020-01-02 00:00:00': 'Justin', '2020-01-03 00:00:00': 'Donald'}, 'color': {'2020-01-01 00:00:00': 'blue', '2020-01-02 00:00:00': 'red', '2020-01-03 00:00:00': 'green'}, 'number': {'2020-01-01 00:00:00': 1, '2020-01-02 00:00:00': 2, '2020-01-03 00:00:00': 9}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(f"{df}\n")

                       name  color  number
2020-01-01 00:00:00  Justin   blue       1
2020-01-02 00:00:00  Justin    red       2
2020-01-03 00:00:00  Donald  green       9
```

final df

```
df = (
    df
    .reset_index(names="date")
    .pivot(index="date", columns="name", values=["color", "number"])
    .fillna("")
)
df.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in df.columns.values]
print(df)

                    color_Donald color_Justin number_Donald number_Justin
date                                                                     
2020-01-01 00:00:00                      blue                           1
2020-01-02 00:00:00                       red                           2
2020-01-03 00:00:00        green                          9
```